# memcpy copying partly over itself

Tags: c, memcpy

Is this ok?

```
char buf[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
memcpy(buf, buf + 1, 2);
```

Does having a bigger datatype make any difference? I know I could use memmove(), but I'm just curious.

Comment: -1: what hapenned when you tried?

Comment: +1, because I disagree with pmg's -1. "What happened when you looked it up in the standard?", maybe, but there's a real risk in experimenting with this kind of thing, that you might try it and it "works", with result `{1,2,2}` in the buffer. Then what use is the advice to try it? Will it still work next week, or when you turn on optimization, or on your customers' computers?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I agree. The OP's example will (probably) work, depending on the particular target platform implementation of `memcpy`, but that doesn't make it a good idea!

Comment: Thing is: he says *"I know I could use memmove()"* and he still asks if `memcpy()` is ok. How does he know he could use memmove and **NOT KNOW** not to use memcpy with overlapping objects?

Comment: @pmg: I guess I was somewhat unclear. I somehow failed to found a definite answer for it being undefined behavior, but obviously didn't leave such thing in code. I tried it out of curiosity, and it worked for my compiler in this particular case.

Comment: The GNU C Library has switched the implementation of memcpy around a few times. Sometimes it's even different for i686 vs i386 vs x86_64.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The effects of `memcpy` are not defined when the input and output overlap. You should use `memmove`.

Answer (score 5):

Not okay. You **must** use `memmove` when the source and destination overlap.

It *might* work with `memcpy`, depending on your compiler's implementation, but that is not something you should rely on!

---

A typical naive implementation might be a byte-by-byte copy (uint8) like this:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;

void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num )
{
    const uint8* pSrc = (const uint8*)source;
    const uint8* const pSrcEnd = pSrc + num;
    uint8* pDst = (uint8*)destination;

    while (pSrc != pSrcEnd)
        *(pDst++) = *(pSrc++);

    return destination;
}
```

which would work okay with your `memcpy(buf, buf + 1, 2)`, but less well with `memcpy(buf + 1, buf, 2)`

Answer (score 4):

The behavior is undefined if the memory regions overlap, so this is not ok.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour, but I have used it like so,

```
char buf[] = {0, 1, 2, 3);
memcpy(buf, buf+2, 2);
```

where the end point of the destination is less than the start point of the source.
You should still use memmove to be sure...

Comment: The GNU C Library has switched the implementation of memcpy around a few times. Sometimes it's even different for i686 vs i386 vs x86_64.